# Ubuntu 16.04 won't restart after clean installation

Tags: system-installation

I followed instructions for downloading Ubuntu 16.04 and placing it on a USB stick for live running and installation.

I chose to erase everything from my hard disk on installation, and opted to install third party software as appropriate and necessary.

The installation process seem to progress without incident.  Eventually, I got a pop up that said I could continue using Ubuntu, but nothing could be saved unless I restarted, so I chose to restart.  Nothing happened, and I was eventually left with a blinking cursor.

I tried restarting my computer again with the USB stick removed and after resetting the BIOS.  I ended up getting a choice of boot options but, regardless of what I selected, my system never booted.

I re-used my USB stick to boot into trial mode, but when I get there now, my only option is to double click on the "install" option.  There's nothing else there.

I've seen similar reports by others and some suggested "fixes", but I am a complete newbie with Linux and have no idea what any of that means.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you reset i your _BIOS_, what were the boot options given you, what other similar fixes did you try ? These answers would make it easier to help you.

Comment: If you have nothing to loose go for a re-install or may be your pen-drive or ISO is corrupt missing some files.

Comment: Are you able to burn the Ubuntu Live .iso to DVD? My experience is that you'll have no trouble if you install from DVD. Also, by resetting the BIOS **after** installing, you might have tripped yourself up. Set the BIOS to UEFI mode and try to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for the quick replies.  I decided to rebuild the Ubuntu Live .iso using the Universal USB Installer and try again.  I decided to check the box to reformat the pen-drive thinking that something may be corrupted.  After I did that, the install went flawlessly.  I had previously used the same pen-drive to install Linux Mint (which failed), so maybe the pen-drive got corrupted from that?